# Paypal Cordova Plugin - IOS - Phonegap - 'error: please make sure all fields have been entered;

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins

Has anyone managed to successfully integrate the Paypal Cordova Plugin (https://github.com/shazron/PayPalPlugin) into an IOS Phonegap App?

Ive followed all instructions and all works great in sandbox mode - but when I set the environment to 'live' I get the error 'please make sure all fields have been entered', i notice that this happens even if you type in a incorrect ID / Password combo.

No errors in the console - really frustrating - I cant find any useful info to help.

Any tips would be great-fully received!

Comment: This plugin is now undergoing a complete overhaul and re-write under new management. Are you still having issues?

Comment: If any of the below answers presented a solution to your question, please accept their answer by clicking on the check mark beside their answer. This will help future users searching for an answer to the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had also an issue with the live mode.
I forked and updated the plugin with the MPL library because the initial library was the problem.
You can find the code here: https://github.com/searchtool/PayPalPlugin

Maybe it is not perfect, I am not an Objective C dev but it works for us, the app is on the AppStore.
Hope it helps and not too late.

Comment: fantastic - just in the nick of time!  I'll give it a go tomorrow!

Comment: Tried but failed to implement your plugin Searchtool, whichever way I approach setting up the files I always get a load of Apple Mach-0 Linker Errors, which I've no idea how to resolve..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the plugin at https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin. This has been completely re-written and tested using the newest SDK from PayPal. This is a major re-write and fix from the old repository you tried at first and under new management has been repaired and re-released. Hope this helps.